# How to tag and upload image on user's facebook profile profile using JS and API

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs

**How can I tag and upload an image to my app's user profile?**

I am using following code which is not working for me.
The user has given upload, post, offline_access scopes to my app on the landing page of my app after that on result page.

I'm using this code:

```
function graphStreamPublish(session){
            showLoader(true);

            FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',
                {
                    message     : "trying to publish image",

                    picture     : 'http://localhost:8085/myweb/images/arranged2.jpg',
                    name        : 'This is my demo Facebook application (JS SDK)!',
                    description : 'It is fun to write Facebook App!!'

            },function(response) {
                showLoader(false);

                if (!response || response.error) {
                    alert('Error occured');
                } else {
                    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                }
            });
        }
```

Do I need to do Fb.init on the page as well?
I put above code after `<body>` tag is that right?
How can I tag the user on the same image?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, the facebook-server will try to download the picture-url, as this url is `localhost`, this will fail because `localhost` means the Facebook-Server and not your server in this context. Replace the picture-url with a public available URL.

Comment: thank u for the help. I replaced the image url with "http://www.thefinestwriter.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/online_dating.jpg" but still its not working neither it is giving any error or dialog or anything.  I am testing the app on localhost. Can that be reason for it?

Comment: @ theomega somebody please help.